# Sharepoint Client - list all users

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I need to list all the users of a SharePoint 2019 domain in a WPF grid.
I know how to list the users of a given site collection, however how do I list all the users?

For example, the user "Engineer 10" is not a user of the "Sales" site collection, however, I want to be able to list him as it is shown in the SharePoint "Invite people" window

[image: Shaorepoint "invite People" window]

Here is my code

### XAML

```
<Window xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  x:Class="MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="250" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="COL_ID" Header="ID"  Width="*"   Binding="{Binding [0]}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="COL_NAME" Header="USER"  Width="*"   Binding="{Binding [1]}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="COL_EMAIL" Header="E-mail"  Width="*"   Binding="{Binding [2]}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

class MainWindow
{
    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        List<object[]> Userlist = new List<object[]>();
        Userlist.Clear();
        Grid.ItemsSource = null;
        Grid.Items.Clear();
        SP.ClientContext ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://dc/Sites/Sales/");
        SP.Web Website = ClientContext.Web;
        SP.UserCollection Users = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb.SiteUsers;
        SP.Web root = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb;
        ClientContext.Load(root);
        ClientContext.Load(Users);
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var us in Users)
        {
            ClientContext.Load(us);
            ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Userlist.Add(new User(us.Id, us.Title, us.Email).Fields);
        }
        Grid.ItemsSource = Userlist;
        ClientContext.Dispose();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public User(idin, namein, Emailin)
    {
        Values(0) = idin;
        Values(1) = namein;
        Values(2) = Emailin;
    }
    public object[] Fields = new object[4];

    public object Values
    {
        get
        {
            return Fields[test_number];
        }
        set
        {
            Fields[test_number] = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of my code. You can see "Engineer 10" is not listed

[image: WPF Window]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are getting users from a site collection. If the users are not added in the site collection, you cannot retrieve them.

In fact, users are from AD. If you have user profile service configured, users information would be stored in the UPS. So you could try to get all users  from UPS.

Comment: Can you give me more details? Do I have to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfile and peoplemanager? Doesn't this require needing the credentials of each user?